# iOS: Better justification with CoreText

Tags: ios, objective-c, whitespace, core-text, justify

I'm floating some text around an image using `CoreText` and `kCTJustifiedTextAlignment` to show the text justiefied - but with larger images, smaller text-areas and less whitespaces `CoreText` does not only widen whitespaces but also the margin between the letters.

See here:
[image: badly justified]

This sometimes looks really awful, so I searched for some alternatives or workarounds but only found the advice to do it myself by adding more whitespaces after each whitespace to match the width and using `kCTLeftTextAlignment`. 
It sounds like a lot of snares to deal with, so I thought, I'd ask here, maybe anyone has an idea how to deal with that issue.

Comment: try using softhyphens, this will not completly eliminate the problem, but will reduce the times it will occur.

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to make this better. The next word is too long to fit in the same row with the "seiner" word, so this is what happens....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic question here is "so what do you want?" The other obvious answer is "full justify unless... some rules I'm going to make up like if there's only one word."

If you want that kind of control, then you need to drop down to the `CTLine` level and create justified lines only when you want them. Assuming you already know a bit about CoreText, this code should hopefully make sense. It justifies the line only if it isn't the last line of the paragraph.

```
  CFIndex lineCharacterCount = CTTypesetterSuggestLineBreak(self.typesetter, startIndex, boundsWidth);
  CTLineRef line = CTTypesetterCreateLine(self.typesetter, CFRangeMake(startIndex, lineCharacterCount));

  // Fetch the typographic bounds
  CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &(*ascent), &(*descent), &(*leading));

  // Full-justify all but last line of paragraphs
  NSString *string = self.attributedString.string;
  NSUInteger endingLocation = startIndex + lineCharacterCount;
  if (endingLocation >= string.length || [string characterAtIndex:endingLocation] != '\n') {
    CTLineRef justifiedLine = CTLineCreateJustifiedLine(line, 1.0, boundsWidth);
    CFRelease(line);
    line = justifiedLine;
  }
```

So we create a normal `CTLine` based on the `CTTypesetter` suggestion. Then we apply some rule (only one word? Not the end of the paragraph? Whatever.) If we pass, then we create a new, justified line. (I'm not certain why `CTTypesetter` can't create a justified line itself.)

For a full example of this, see [PinchText](https://github.com/rnapier/richtext-coretext/blob/master/PinchText/Classes/PinchTextLayer.m). It's much more complicated than you need, but it shows how to do all the layout with lots of comments.

Comment: @RobNapier, you're awesome. really great work there.

Comment: @RobNapier, Really appreciate your work there. But somehow the stroke or fill color stopped working for iOS 10, I've posted a question here: [CoreGraphics ignores CGContextSetFillColorWithColor and draws black](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42274667/593709) Could you give some tips there?